# How to move mysql database online with python

Tags: python

I have built an app that uses mysql database with Python, I would love to share some functionalities with different applications and that calls for an online database feature, kindly give me some insights over how i can move a python mysql database to online and how to make calls to it in order to facilitate for sharing of data between different applications.

Comment: [middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware_(distributed_applications)) this may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what you are calling a python database but there are some options here that you might want to consider

- First, use heroku to host your app and  heroku postgress  to host your database
- Or you can use an EC2 aws machine to host your app and it's database (in case it's a custom code that you can't call from a browser using heroku)

with both of these options you can access you database and the appp with the second one you can install other services such as ssh and other.